# Centering xlabel position in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, figure

How can I center the position of an xlabel such that it is in the middle of a figure? I would like the center of the xlabel to be alligned with the center of a caption when using LaTeX

Comment: The `xlabel` command creates a `text` graphics object for the current (`gca`) axes graphics object and not figure. It is a convience function that sets the `XLabel` property of the current axes graphics object. Could you give some more information on what you mean by "center of a caption"? Do you mean the title of the current axes object (set using the `title`-function)?

Comment: By "center of caption" I mean the center of the figure text (caption) in LaTeX. If I insert a figure, the x axis label sits to the right of the center of the figure text. I would like to move the x axis label a bit to the left to allign the two, if possible.

Comment: Could you post some MATLAB code perhaps? Or maybe a screenshot of your MATLAB figure with the problem to see. You are inserting figures using LaTeX? A bit confused :)

Comment: I am using the MATLAB figures in my LaTeX document. I just want the x axis label in the MATLAB figure to be centered over the caption. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post pictures yet, otherwise I would have done so, but here's a link to a screenshot. I would like "Time(s)" to be centered around the black line: http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/5856/examplef.jpg

Comment: Did you ever get it working properly?

Answer (score 1):

The `xlabel` function creates a `string` graphics object and sets this as the `XLabel` property of the current axes object. You can define properties for this `string` objects when calling `xlabel`. You can adjust the position of the center of the string object by adjusting the `Position` property which is by defaults set to [0 0].

First you get what the position is right now (after plotting and using `xlabel`):

```
vec_pos = get(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Position');
```

Then you update the position (adjust x with -0.5 for instance):

```
set(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Position', vec_pos + [-0.5 0 0]);
```

This is done in the data-units by default of the x-axis as far as the documentation goes. It seems to me that the label "Time (s)" is located at 0.13s (according to your figure). Let's adjust it to the left with 0.008 seconds to 0.122s (a "guestimate").

Force it to be "data" units and adjust with 0.008:

```
str_defaultUnits = get(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Units'); % copy this
set(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Units', 'data'); % change it
set(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Position', vec_pos + [-0.008 0 0]); % adjust position
set(get(gca, 'XLabel'), 'Units', str_defaultUnits); % set it back as it was
```

**On another note**: What you trying to achieve is somewhat wrong I would say :) The label of an axis should not be aligned by force to the entire figure caption. Why do this? The figure caption is centered on the entire figure, not just the plotting area. I fear it will look weird in the end. Your choice of course.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. The xlabel disappears. I have tried this as well, but the xlabel still disappears: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/111332

Comment: hmm could it be that the units are likely not correct since you are using an image? Overlooked that one. What does the `vec_pos` give you (without calling any of the `xlabel` examples I gave)?

Comment: vec_pos = [2.9942 -3.2705 1.0001]. If I change any of the numbers, the label disappears. I don't think it has to do with units since I am exporting the image at the very end of the script.

Comment: The label dissapears ... hmm. Mysterious. Always remember the Z-axis coordinate. It defaults to zero of not explicitly set. Setting the two first only, as I do it is wrong. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have just tried your updated code. Does it work for you? It does not move my xlabel. You might be right assuming it will look weird, I just wanted to try it.

Comment: It probably moves it, but only very little (-0.008). Have you tried using my code, but use, say, -0.1, -0.5, or even -1.0 as the first element in the adjustment instead of -0.008? I say this because the `vec_pos` you posted before is likely in 'data' units. If 2.9942 is in the center of the plot, then adjusting its x-pos +/-1.0 should move it enough to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

The specifics of what you're trying to do will depend on your matlab print settings and latex options (e.g. caption raggedright or centering), but this should at least put your xlabel in the centre of the figure, rather than the centre of the axes.

```
fh=figure;
ah=axes;
plot(ah,[2.0:10],[2:10])
xlh=xlabel(ah,'my xlabel');
drawnow;
xlh_pos=get(xlh,'position');
ah_pos=get(ah,'position');
x_lim=xlim;

xlh_pos_fig=0.5;%put it in the middle
xlh_pos(1)=(xlh_pos_fig - ah_pos(1))*(x_lim(2)-x_lim(1))/ah_pos(3)+x_lim(1);
set(xlh,'position',xlh_pos);
```